# Get UISwitch state -Xamarin

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios

I am building an iOS App using Xamarin. I looked around but couldn't quite find a way to determine the state of my UISwitch.

I created the UI using Storyboard. The switch's Action name is "Switch"

In my FirstViewController I have

```
        partial void Switch(NSObject sender)
        {
            // I am trying to find the state of the switch
            // here and then do something depending on its state
        }
```

I tried seeing sender

```
string S=sender.ToString();
```

I get:

```
S="<UISwitch: 0x14653dc0; frame = (61 425; 51 31); opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x14653ea0>>"
```

I also saw in the Apple developer website that there should be a isOn I can check but couldn't figure out how to get it.

Cheers!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just use

```
bool state = ((UISwitch)sender).On;
```

to get the state.

Answer (score 1):

You're not seeing the isOn property because you've declared sender as an NSObject instead of a UISwitch.

Answer (score 1):

**Xamarin 5.10:**

```
var sampleSwitch = new UISwitch ();
            sampleSwitch.Frame = new CoreGraphics.CGRect (100f,100f,10f,10f);
            sampleSwitch.ValueChanged += delegate {
                if (sampleSwitch.On) {                  
                    Console.WriteLine ("TRUE"); 
                } else {
                    Console.WriteLine ("FALSE");
                }
            };
            this.View.AddSubview (sampleSwitch);
```